# HTML CSS design: div growing in size

Tags: html, css

Following some instructions given in another question, I've rewritten a web page used to print pdf and to be shown in the web. Here's some code:

```
 /** CSS File **/
 body {
    background-color: lightcyan;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 268mm;
    margin-bottom: 13mm;
    margin-left: 11mm;
    margin-right: 12mm;
    margin-top: 10mm;
    width: 187mm;
 }
 img {
    margin: 0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
 }
 div.ClrOvFlw, div.Pedice {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
 }
 div.Left, div.Left75 {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
 }
 div.Right, div.Right25 {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
 }
div.Left75 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 20.74mm;
    margin-right: 1mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    width: 129mm;
}
div.Right25 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20.74mm;
    margin-left: 1mm;
    padding: 0mm;
    width: 51mm;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<body>
    <div class="ClrOvFlw">
        <div  class="Left75">
            <img id="Logo" src="../Box Logo Testata/Logo.jpg" alt="Mark">
        </div>
        <div class="Right25">
            <div id="Bandiera">
                <img id="BandieraImg" src="" alt="ITA">
            </div>
            <div id="MadeInItaly">
                MADE IN ITALY
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I've calculated the dimensions on a given template. If I don't put srcs in the img tags everything is fine, but when I put them on, the Right25 div flows on another row because the Left75 div becomes bigger. Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kz6mq2vg/) to fiddle.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Here's the image you requested.
[image]

Comment: What's the size of the logo image?

Comment: Why do u expect `.ClrOvFlw` to have a `129 + 1 + 1 + 51` mm `width`?

Comment: @stig-js 71.97x20.74mm (gimp).

Comment: @Trix What do you mean?

Comment: @IssamTP I can't reproduce the error, could you post an screenshot? e.x. https://jsfiddle.net/kz6mq2vg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the left element is increasing in size, it's that the right element is being pushed in from the right side of the screen. Why? because the css is making room for a scrollbar, and your width values are all fixed length.

It's being caused by the `overflow: auto` CSS being applied to `div.ClrOvFlw` here:

```
div.ClrOvFlw, div.Pedice {
clear: both;
overflow: auto;
}
```

For some reason, when you add an image to the src, the CSS is expecting the requirement of a scrollbar - Can't say for sure, but I would imagine it has to do with the size of the image before the constraints of the div it is being put into are applied. If the resolution of the image is large enough that - were it not shrunk to fit inside the div - it would require an overflow to be seen. You can test this by putting an image that is naturally small in as the src instead, like `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif`. Note that the divs fit as expected when this is your source.

Your solution is either remove the `overflow: auto` from the `ClrOvFlw` div, or resize your source image so that its natural resolution is small enough that it would fit within the prescribed height of the containing div.

Note: the fixed length stuff is an issue because the containers can't respond to the reduced space - 25% of the containing div is no longer 51mm. You could try using % widths instead if that is an option - it may also alleviate the issue without having to redo your image.

Comment: The problem was overflow: auto. I can't resize images, because in the final release I will not have any control on images or whatever it will come later. I used % in the web version and everything is fine.